# Build for iPhone is not working

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I've run into a strange issue when I wanted to start debugging an app on a real device.

Issue appear at build sounds like this:

> "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(696,3): error :
>   Failed to resolve "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1
>   Acr.UserDialogs.IUserDialogs::ConfirmAsync(System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String)"
>   reference from "Acr.UserDialogs.Interface, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" 5> 5>Build FAILED."

The strange part is that if I just run it on the simulator (without changing anything else) it works. Also if I select "Don't link" option from Project Options -> iOS Build -> Linker Options -> Linker behavior: Don't link it works also on device.
I've tried to use different versions of that Package (Acr.UserDialogs), but nothing changed with that.

Why is this happening and what should I do in order to be able to run app on device with 'Linker behavior: Link SDK assemblies only'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The primary target of iOS linker is to reduce the size of the bundle. In doing so, it will also remove code, that is not used, which can lead to many problems. Now I cannot really tell what your problem is. In my case, e.g., constructors were removed, because they were nowhere called. This was however not true, because classes were created with an IoC, therefore constructors were used, despite the absence of direct references to them.
If you are the author of the problematic assembly, you can mark classes that cause linker problems with [Preserve] attribute. This will tell linker to leave these classes in peace.
If you are not, you can exclude just one assembly from linking prosess by supplying --linkskip=AssemblyName in mtouch argument is iOS project properties.

Comment: I've added `linkship=Acr.UserDialogs.Interface --linkship=System.Threading.Tasks` and also other combination of those or just Acr.Dialogs but same error

Comment: @AlexStefan you typed linkship not linkskip.